# Excel adding data based on current data

Tags: excel, addition, conditional-statements, vba

I'm trying to write a macro that i can run which will allow me to simply sort a range of orders into what i like to call categories.

The basic idea is that we get orders through, and we generally have to print a different type of shipping label for the different items, based on weight, size and value. Unfortunately, there is no easy way of doing this other than going through all orders (sometimes thousands) and copying them into different worksheets to group them into the type of shipping method we need to use.

What i'd like to do (i already have a couple of macros already) - is to look in another sheet whereby we store the item titles, and have a second column within that sheet with a number (1, 2 or 3). For each item, based on it's weight, size or value, which we have already specified - they would be assigned a number. The Macro will look at the item name, if the sales sheet finds a match from column A in the item's sheet, it will then add the correct number specified in the item's sheet to the cell next to the item title in the sales sheet.

Column A-G has all customer details, Column H has the item title. The number i'm wanting to add to the row will be inserted into Column I.

The item's sheet has Column A which is the item title, and Column B is the number assigned to this item.

I have tried to muster a macro up myself, however it's confusing me no end.

Comment: Are you sure this needs to be a macro?  I think I would use a lookup (keyword is VLOOKUP).  Google some examples of that and see if it's what you want.

Comment: It does need to be a macro because it's going to search through *and add the right number* to all entries in the sales sheet, which can contain thousands of entries. I tried looking at VLOOKUP but it seems to only look for strings or values, i want it too look for them and add an entry to the cell on the right which corresponds to the number on the items sheet.

Comment: please add some screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what vlookup is used for

```
 =VLOOKUP(H1, items!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

Put this formula into I1 on the sales sheet and drag it down,  if the items sheet is not in the same workbook , you will need to modify the reference to point to it,

you could obviously write a macro that will insert this formula and drop it down, but it will still be using  vlookup or application.vlookup to get the result

Wildcard searches at the front would be

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&H1, items!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

or both ends would be

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&H1&"*", items!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

NB* BE CAREFUL WITH THIS AS YOU MAY HAVE ITEMS WITH SIMILAR DESCRIPTIONS
 like "apple" and "red apple"

you should always use a product code to do lookups when available

Comment: Would this also add the correct number to the cell to the right of each item in the sales sheet? That's my main concern.

Comment: sorry i mixed up your sheet names, please read my answer again , the formula is to be entered in cell I1 on the sales sheet(drag formula down )  which is where you want the number to be

Comment: I added this particular formula into cell I1 and it just returns "#N/A" - i've checked that all the sheet names and such are correct, the data is in the sheet i want to look at and add to.

Comment: is it an exact match?  the data in both cells need to be identical,  no extra whitespace or  case sizes in the description etc,  Can you paste both data?

Comment: The data is exactly the same in both sheets. No variation in spacing or case sizes. The items sheet has 2 columns. Column A is the item name i'm searching for and column B is the number i want to return into the empty cell.

Comment: N/A means no match is found,    are you sure row 1 of the sales sheet has a product in it?  please drag formula down along the product rows

Comment: My apologies, it does work fine now. The only problem i have is that i do have some fields which are not exactly the same in both sheets, for example, i have a quantity of a particular item which shows as 2x or 3x etc and i'd like to have 1 entry for them so that if the string contains "Ice Scraper" - for example - it adds the number as it is now. Would this be possible? More or less looking for a wildcard.

Comment: ive added these to the answer above

Comment: Steve, the wildcard VLOOKUP is only returning "1" rather than the number associated with the item we have on the items sheet.

Comment: Please see my note ,  Vlookup finds te first match, so there must be another product with the same string somewhere in it, with a 1 ,  id advise you to use product codes instead of description to make this work reliablly,  can you pvt mail me at stevenmartin99@gmail.com and maybe we could see what you have to work with?

Comment: We do use product codes more often than not, however sometimes people purchase 2 or 3 (or more) of a particular item so therefore it will show as "2x Ice", which is where this particular formula trips up. Is there a way for it to ignore the 2x and just look for the string of text?

Comment: i mean do you have a column on the sales page with a product code that code be used as a lookup against the items sheet? it would involve adding the product codes to the items sheet but it would make it work reliably.   in regards your other question  does it have 1x if there is only 1? or is there another column also with the qty ordered that could be used to know there will be a Xx at the start?

Comment: Generally it will just state the item code if it's just 1. I could manually put 2x 3x 4x the item in the items sheet, but this would be unreliable.

Comment: can you make the system always put 1x  when one is ordered just as it does when 2 is ordered,  not on the items sheet , but on the sales sheet  so that we can reliably chop off everything until the first "x "

Comment: did you mean there is a product code with no spaces in it so you might have   "3X 889809" and "889809" if 1 is ordered becuase we could use this to do the lookup then , the issue is that descriptions have spaces in them and product codes generally dont

Comment: When we get our orders through, we get them in an excel spreadsheet which has all the order details etc and it would then have a "Quantity" field. I suppose i could run the VLOOKUP before amending the quantity into the title. I was just hoping there may be a simple way to have it do this with a script or macro. I do, however, have a macro which finds and replaces item titles to shorten them so we can print the labels, however this uses the Find & Replace script. Would there be a way to use this to find the title and "replace" the blank cell with the number?

Comment: yes if you already have a macro , the first thing would be to use the product code or description (if it doesn't yet contain the "2x") to get the number before you start modifying the sales sheet.  Is there a way you can send me the macro code? and i will add the line, comments on StackOverflow are very limited to what you can write in

Comment: The macro i use at the moment is this:

`Sub FindNReplace()
Dim InputRng As Range, ReplaceRng As Range

'Set Range Values
Set InputRng = Range("H1:H5000")
Set ReplaceRng = Sheets("royal").Range("A1:B100")

'Spin through replacement range and perform replace
For Each Rng In ReplaceRng.Columns(1).Cells
    InputRng.Replace what:=Rng.Value, replacement:=Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
Next
End Sub`

This finds item titles and replaces them with shorter titles depicted in another sheet.